# How can I rewrite over something in a file in my python program

Tags: python, file, tkinter

I am making a password manager where it stores users passwords in a text file and I want to give the option of deleting a previous password that they created. For this I want to use a Messagebox to tell them this like so `messagebox.showinfo('Error''Password has already been generated for this, do you want to overwrite?')` And if they say yes for it to be over-written. So I know I should read the file but do I pass all file contents into an array at splitting at '-END OF PASSWORD-' and then re-write over the index and join them back together to write the file? NOTE: I am changing the storage of the key and encrypting the files!

```
# Main Function Function
def mainCode():
    # Generate Password Function
    def generate():

        # Submit Function
        def submited():
            toomanypasswords = False
            # Call the password generator
            setPassword()
            # Get user input from the entry
            usrinput = userInput.get()
            # Set a splitter for writing to the file
            splitter = ': '
            # If passwordenc.txt exists:
            if os.path.isfile('passwordenc.txt'):
                # Open passwordenc.txt and set it as password_file
                with open('passwordenc.txt', 'ab') as password_file:
                    # Combine what the password is for and the generated password
                    var = usrinput + splitter + generatePassword
                    # Encrypt ^^
                    encrypted = f.encrypt(bytes(var.encode('utf-8')))
                    # Write the encrypted combo to password_file
                    password_file.write(encrypted)
                    # Needed for seperating the passwords together
                    password_file.write(b"--END OF PASSWORD--")
            # If passwordenc.txt does not exist:
            else:
                # Open passwordenc.txt and set it as password_file
                with open('passwordenc.txt', 'wb')as password_file:
                    # Combine what the password is for and the generated password
                    var = usrinput + splitter + generatePassword
                    # Encrypt the combo
                    encrypted = f.encrypt(bytes(var.encode('utf-8')))
                    # Write the encrypted combo to password_file
                    password_file.write(encrypted)
                    # Needed for seperating the passwords together
                    password_file.write(b"--END OF PASSWORD--")

            # Change the label to what the password is for
            passwordUse.config(text=usrinput)
            # Change the label to the generated password
            passwordLbl.set(generatePassword)

        # Destroy the menu options
        menu.destroy()

        # Create a new window object as generate
        generate = Tk()
        # Same size will be defined in variable for center screen in Tk_Width and Tk_height
        Tk_Width = 500
        Tk_Height = 240

        # calculate coordination of screen and window form
        x_Left = int(generate.winfo_screenwidth() / 2 - Tk_Width / 2)
        y_Top = int(generate.winfo_screenheight() / 2 - Tk_Height / 2)

        # Write following format for center screen
        generate.geometry("+{}+{}".format(x_Left, y_Top))
        # Set up a string variable to change the text
        passwordLbl = tk.StringVar()
        # Set the text
        passwordLbl.set('-----')
        # Set window title
        generate.title('Generate Password')
        # set window geometry
        generate.geometry('500x240')
        # Set the entry as a string variable to get it's contents
        userInput = StringVar()
        # Create a frame for the grid
        genFrame = tk.Frame(generate)
        # Create a new label
        entryLabel = tk.Label(genFrame, text='Enter what it is for:')
        entryLabel.grid(row=1, column=0)
        # Create an entry for what the password is for
        entry = tk.Entry(genFrame, textvariable=userInput)
        entry.grid(row=1, column=1)
        # Create a new label
        label2 = tk.Label(genFrame, text='What the password is for:')
        label2.grid(row=2, column=0)
        # Create a new label
        passwordUse = tk.Label(genFrame, text='-----')
        passwordUse.grid(row=2, column=1)
        # Create a new label
        label3 = tk.Label(genFrame, text='The Password:')
        label3.grid(row=3, column=0)
        # Create a new label
        passwordLabel = tk.Label(genFrame, textvariable=passwordLbl)
        passwordLabel.grid(row=3, column=1)
        # Create a new button for submitting
        submitBtn = Button(genFrame, text='Submit', command=submited)
        submitBtn.grid(row=4, column=1)
        # Pack the frame
        genFrame.pack()
        # Run the window
        generate.mainloop()
```

Comment: There's a lot of code here, when it seems that all you are asking is how to overwrite a string in a file. Please try to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Suggest to use sqlite3 db instead of text file to store the passwords.

Comment: I suggest to write a short code describing your problem

Comment: I edited it to make it more simple